# Radio button on checked returns undefined in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I need to show values in radio button using ng-repeat and show default checked. Checking condition is not based on the value assigned in each radio.
So it shows checked and all values are displayed. But when submitting form, it returns "undefined". I need to select the option once atleast to send correct value.

```
<div ng-repeat="size1 in key.values">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="products.sizevalue" name="size1" value="{{size1.value_id}}" ng-checked="'{{size1.qr_size}}' === '{{size}}'"  />
    <label>{{size1.title}}</label>
</div>
```

In above snippet, I need to show "size1.title" in label, post value should be "size1.value_id" and checked value to be based on "size1.qr_size" which is compared with "size".
What am I missing?

Comment: ng-checked, does not take interpolation symbols. Remove `{{}}`, use `size1.qr_size=== size`

Comment: tried that too. It does not show checked in this case.

Comment: Whether the input is checked is decided by the ng-model property `products.sizevalue` is true or false.

Comment: Then how do I set it to true if my comparison is not with the value in ng-model?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your problem I think you should use  `ng-init` instead of  `value`

Comment: I am fetching value from json having multiple values out of which I want to display all "title" in label, value of each option should contain "value_id" and I want checked value to be compared with "qr_size" but do not want to pass "qr_size" in ng-model.

    "1234":{
        "title":"12cm x 10cm",
       "value_id":"1234",
        "qr_size":"12x10"
    },
    "5678":{
        "title":"3 cm x 5cm",
        "value_id":"5678",
        "qr_size":"3x5"
    },
    "7654":{
        "title":"18cm x 10cm",
       "value_id":"7654",
        "qr_size":"18x10"
    }

Comment: need to show "18cm x 10cm" checked, i have qr_size="18x10" based on which i want to put condition. Also post data should contain value_id. Thus, post "7654".
I hope this is clear now. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a hidden variable and binding the value to radio button event solves the problem.
For the initial undefined value in radio button, I have set the initial value to the hidden variable and onchange of radio event, binded the value to this variable.